# How to run shell script on Teamcity Windows agent?

Tags: windows, shell, jenkins, teamcity

We used to use Jenkins as our CI tool, I can run shell script in Jenkins windows slave, the steps is:

> 1.install cygwin on Windows slave
>
> 2.add step in Jenkins as shell script
>
> 3.add "export PATH=/cygdrive/c/dev/tools/cygwin/bin:$PATH " as the first line

then I can execute any shell script in Jenkins.

Now we need to move to teamcity, and I found above steps not work on teamcity.

when I run a "Command line" and set the first line as "export PATH=/cygdrive/c/dev/tools/cygwin/bin:$PATH", it gives me an error as "'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Is there any way to resolve it? I don't want to re-write our shell script into cmd.

Comment: Did you install cygwin on the build agent machines (if they are different to the server) and did you restart the service afterwards?

Comment: Are you wanted to execute the shell script when a build is triggered? I'm confused with "on TeamCity agent".

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd Yes I install cygwin on the build agent and restart it already

Comment: @Brandon Yes I want to run shell script on Windows slave, the agent is mean "slave" in Teamcity

Answer (score 3):

This is quite easy to resolve. The error does not come from Cygwin of course, but from CMD. The `export` command only makes sense within a Bash script; cmd has no way of knowing what to do with it.

What you need to do is simply specify to CMD that the script should run using Cygwin's command interpreter (`bash`). So you can either just specify the long path to the `bash` executable and your script, as in

```
C:\dev\tools\cygwin\bin\bash D:\myscript.sh
```

or you can just add the path to the cygwin directory to your machine's PATH variable. You can do this by changing the System Settings and append the path there, or you can do it as part of your script above:

```
# this is not necessary if you have already changed the System Variable to include the path
set PATH=C:\dev\tools\cygwin\bin;%PATH%

bash D:\myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chance you already have Git installed on the agent with Git Bash. Following is how I run `npm` commands without changing the `PATH` variable

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c "cd Source && npm install && npm run build"
```

Comment: Directly specifying the path was already covered in my answer from Dec 2016. If you have new info to add to an existing answer you should just edit it and add the extra information. Otherwise it's just duplication.

Comment: What you are saying is valid to some extent. But this answer is more towards using what's existing - Git bash. I have addressed a common mistake whereby not wrapping directories in `Program Files` with double quotes. Finally I run multiple commands.

Answer (score 0):

With this, you can run the shell/bash commands:-
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -c "cd Source && npm install && npm run build"

And from Powershell, if you want to run bash scripts :-

& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe' .\build.sh